# Increasing the length of a frame and push following strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm looking for a tool that I could use to extend one frame of a strip that I have so that the following strips position gets automatically adjusted.

|--strip a--|--strip b--|--strip c--|

Let's say that strip b has one particular frame that I'd like to freeze for 2 seconds. Currently what I need to do is to grab strip c (or however many strips are there), hard-cut strip b, then hard-cut the right portion of strip b so that a one frame strip is available. Then I need to manually move the remainder of strip b away from the one frame, extend the one frame to be as long as I want it to be and finally adjust the position of both the remainder of strip b and strip c.

Can this get any easier? Is there maybe a plugin for Blender that does that?

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered the sequence "Shift-K", "A", "E", "G" :)

1. Position cursor on the frame you want to make a still from
2. Hard cut (Shift-K)
3. Go to next frame
4. Hard cut (Shift-K)
5. Go to previous frame (cursor left)
6. Extend from frame (E) <-- This does the trick!
7. Grab the remainder and move it as far right as you'd like